# Java program for recursively reversing an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, reverse

I am supposed to be writing a program to reverse the numbers in an array recursively. I don't really know much code at this point. This is what I have so far.

This is the reverse method itself:

```
  public static void reverse(int[] array, int i, int j)
  {
    if (i < j)
    {
      int temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
      reverse(array, ++i, --j);
```

I am not sure if this is even right. I then have the main method.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter size of the array");
   int n = input.nextInt();
   int[] array = new int[n];

   for (int i =0; i <array.length; i++)
   {
     System.out.println("Enter number to be inputed into array.");
     array[i] = input.nextInt();

   }
    System.out.println(array);
  }
```

It is not printing out right and prints numbers and letter in text where I think it should be the array.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, could post the whole reverse method?

Comment: I think it's just missing a couple closing braces.

Comment: yeap likely but better make sure.

Comment: Note: The main method isn't actually calling `reverse`.

Comment: That is my code. It is just missing braces like ajb said. It still isn't working though. I can't call my method correctly.

Comment: If your question has been sufficiently answered, you should `accept an answer`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `System.out.println(array);` to this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Then you can see whether or not your method is properly reversing.  Currently, you're not printing the contents of the array, just the memory address where your array resides.

Comment: What is a String? Excuse my probably stupid question.

Comment: `String` is a data type which essentially represents an array of `char`s.  This probably isn't technically write, but a `String` is a data type that holds words, phrases, etc., in much the same way `int` is a data type which holds integers.

Comment: A ummutable sequence of characters.